ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE in Postgres 15
On pg_restore Postgresql throws an error on index creation:
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
Command was: CREATE INDEX inventory_package__name_index ON public.inventory_package USING gin (public.unaccent((name)::text) public.gin_trgm_ops);

Using Postgresql 15

Define unaccent as immutable? (Which it obviously should be judging by its name).

Presumably someone altered the function to mark it immutable:
alter function unaccent(text) immutable;

But since the unaccent function is part of an extension (one also named "unaccent"), this marking is lost during a dump and restore.  You would need to repeat the modification, assuming of course you think that that is the correct thing to do.  It might be better to make a wrapper around the extension's unaccent function and declare that wrapper immutable, and use that.  That way future upgrades will not have the same problem.
